Package '${applicationId}.test' from AndroidManifest.xml is not a valid
How to fix this issue?
Package '${applicationId}.test' from AndroidManifest.xml is not a valid Java package name as '${applicationId}' is not a valid Java identifier.
I am getting thus error in android studio while building apk

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please [edit] your question and include your AndroidManifest.xml. Also take a look at [ask] and How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example
